# Repeat at 10 second interval - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, time, timer

1) Need the function to start a 1:00:10 PM
2) Need the function to re-run at a multiple of every 10 seconds (but incase the function runs over 10 seconds, need it to skip that and goto the next 10 second start)...

Currently this isnt working

```
persistant 10SecStart

if isempty(10SecStart)
    10SecStart = '01:00:10';
end

t1=timer('TimerFcn','runmyfile');
startat(t1,10SecStart);

tic

FUNCTION HERE % Should take less than 10 Seconds, but sometimes is more than 10 Sec but less than 20 seconds. 

toc
toc = elapsedTime;

if elapsedTime < '00:00:10'

10SecStart = 10SecStart + '00:00:10'

else

10SecStart = (10SecStart + ('00:00:10'- elapsedTime) + '00:00:10' )

end
```

Comment: Regarding this line and similar: `10SecStart + '00:00:10'`. You can't do math with strings. It does not return what you expect in this case. Convert all times and dates to `datenum` and calculate using these numbers.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to implement is [fully supported by the timer object](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/handling-timer-queuing-conflicts.html). Setting the `BusyMode` to `'drop';` causes the next execution to be skipped in case the previous is not finished.